# foreach statement echo once if nested foreach is empty?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

OK I have a foreach statement searching for a keyword across 3 multisite blogs in wordpress like so:

```
<?php
 foreach ( $blogs as $blog ):
 switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
 $search = new WP_Query($query_string);  
                     if ($search->found_posts>0) {
                            foreach ( $search->posts as $post ) {
echo "POST CONTEN";
                            }
                    }elseif ($search->found_posts===0) {
                        # code...
                        $notfound = true;
                    }
        endforeach;
if ($notfound) {
    # code...
    echo "POST NOT FOUND";
}
```

This works fine if there are no posts using the keyword across all thre blogs it echos the POST NOT FOUND but if there is a post on blog 1 but not on blog 2 or 3 it still echos POST NOT FOUND why? 
Chris
//*****************UPDATE**************************************************************/

```
<?php
 $searchfor = get_search_query(); // Get the search query for display in a headline
 $query_string=esc_attr($query_string); // Escaping search queries to eliminate potential MySQL-injections
 $blogs = get_blog_list( 0,'all' );
 $notfound = true;
 foreach ( $blogs as $blog ):
 switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
 $search = new WP_Query($query_string);  
                     if ($search->found_posts>0) {
                         $notfound = false;
                    }
                    if($notfound){
                        ?>
                        <div class="post">
                                <h2><?php _e('Ingen resultater'); ?></h2>
                                <p><?php _e('Beklager, vi fant ingen innlegg som samsvarer med ditt søk: ' . get_search_query()); ?></p>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }else{
                         foreach ( $search->posts as $post ) {
echo "content";
                            }
                    }
        endforeach;

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is backwards. You should start with a "nothing found" condition, and change it to false when something is found:

```
$not_found = true;

while ...
   if ($search->found_posts != 0) {
     $not_found = false;
   }
}
if ($not_found) {
  echo 'nothing found'; // $not_found is true
} else {
  echo 'found something'; // $not_found is false
}
```

Comment: OK yes this works I my problem here is that i need the if else inside of the first foreach and when I do this is echos not found 3 time one for each blog it didn't find something on...

Comment: in that case, `foreach($blogs ...) { if ($found) echo "Found something in $blog"; } else { echo "found nothing in $blog" }`-type thing would do the trick

Comment: I've edited my code this is what i thought i was doing but it still echos not found three times not only once..

Comment: fixed it i added another if($notfound) out side the loop to only echo it once

Answer (score -1):

Sorry about the formatting. Just copied your code here. Do the opposite of what your doing, look at the variable $found here.

```
<?php
 $found = false;
 foreach ( $blogs as $blog ):
 switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
 $search = new WP_Query($query_string);  
                     if ($search->found_posts>0) {
                            foreach ( $search->posts as $post ) {
echo "POST CONTEN";
                            }
                      $found = true;
                    }elseif ($search->found_posts===0) {
                        # code...
                    }
        endforeach;
if ($found == false) {
    # code...
    echo "POST NOT FOUND";
}
```